# Json.NET Schema: Custom ErrorType when using a custom JSON validation rule

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jsonschema

I'm using [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) .NET library.

Let's say I have defined a JSON schema like:

```
JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
    'type': 'object',
    'required' : ['name'],
    'properties': {
        'name': {'type':'string'},
        'roles': {'type': 'array'}
    }
}");
```

Now I'm validating a JSON object (note that I'm not defining the `name` property):

```
JObject user = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'roles': ['Developer', 'Administrator']
}");

user.IsValid(schema, out IList<ValidationError> errors);

Debug.WriteLine(errors[0].ErrorType);
```

The output of the last line will be `Required`. This way I know the specific error type at run time and I can make decisions according this error type programmatically.

My problem is that when I'm working with custom validations rules I'm not able to define a custom error type. So all my custom validators will create an error instance with the `ErrorType` property equal to `Validator`, like in the following example:

Defining a custom validation rule:

```
class MyCustomValidator : JsonValidator
{
    public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
    {
        var s = value.ToString();
        if (s != "valid")
        {
            context.RaiseError($"Text '{s}' is not valid.");
        }

    }

    public override bool CanValidate(JSchema schema)
    {
        return schema.Type == JSchemaType.String;
    }
}
```

and running the validation using the custom validation rule:

```
JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
  'type': 'object',
  'required' : ['name'],
  'properties': {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'roles': {'type': 'array'}
  }
}");

JObject user = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'Ivalid',
  'roles': ['Developer', 'Administrator']
}");

schema.Validators.Add(new MyCustomValidator()); // adding custom validation rule

user.IsValid(schema, out IList<ValidationError> errors);

Debug.WriteLine(errors[0].ErrorType);
```

The output will be `Validator`.

My question is: Is there a workaround for this case? How can I differentiate the errors produced by my custom validation rules between them and from each other standard errors type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a feedback from the Json.NET Schema's author in a [Github issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/122) opened by me. The author says:

> Hi
>
> ErrorType is an enum so there isn't a way to define new values at
>   runtime. You will need to embed the information about what the error
>   is in the message and test the content.

That is: currently has no way to customize the error type property at runtime.